# Compile an Isomorphic React with Babelify & Grunt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gruntjs, babeljs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to develop an Isomorphic React App from scratch using Grunt, Browserify, Babel, Babelify, ExpressJS, and React. I'm using Grunt to compile my source code to a build directory. When I try to run server.js, which was compiled with Browserify and Babelify, I get this error in my compiled server.js:

```
var xhr = new global.XMLHttpRequest()

TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a function
```

My tries and assumptions:

- I don't know if Browserify is allowed to be used on the server-side since server.js is written in Node.
- The problem may have to do with the fact that I am requiring .JSX files in my Node based server.js file. To fix that, I tried using node-jsx.install but that causes another error.
- I tried using Reactify, but I wasn't sure how to use that with Grunt and Babelify. But I read that Reactify is out-dated, and I'm supposed to use Babel presets.

Gruntfile.js

```
browserify: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          debug: true,
          transform: [
            ['babelify', {'presets': ['es2015', 'react']}, {'node': true}],
          ]
        },
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './src/',
            src: ['./**/*.jsx', './**/*.js', './server.js'],
            dest: './build/'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var config  = require('./config.js');
var routes  = require('./app/js/routes.jsx');
var Html    = require('./app/js/components/html/html.jsx');
var React   = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var Router   = require('react-router');
var RouterLocation = require('history').createLocation;

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/app'));

// route middleware that will happen on every request
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  Router.match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var content = ReactDOM.renderToString(Router.RoutingContext({renderProps}));
      var data = {body: content};
      var html = ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(Html(data));
      res.status(200).send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + html);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  });
});

app.listen(config.port, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at host: %s', config.host);
});
```

Here is a link to my project on Github:

https://github.com/rashadrussell/isomorphicReactApp

Comment: Why not use webpack?

Comment: No particular reason. I already knew Browserify from a previous project, so I stuck with it. I thought they Browserify and Webpack were very similar. I'll try it.

Comment: What does `console.log(global. XMLHttpRequest);` give you?

Comment: console.log(global. XMLHttpRequest); outputs "undefined"

Comment: I think I understand where a big part of my problem is. I'm trying to do server-side rendering and routing. I am using react-router on the server. In my both my server.js file depends on routes.js on the server-side and client.js depends on routes.js on the client-side. Browserify is a client-side dependency manager, and I used it to transform routes.js. This make work with my client.js file, but will break in the server.js file.